# How to design a portable modularized GUI applications?

Tags: user-interface, qt, model, module

There are a lot of flexible, complete, cross-platform, *et cetera*, graphical user interface frameworks. Most of them provide many tools to turn software development easier. When building a desktop application in Qt environment, for example, one usually would have different file types, headers, implementation files, and user-interface files (`.ui`).
Normally, a developer design an application and, once compiled, no changes can be made to user interface.
I would like to know how to create an portable modularized application that could dynamically load personalized user-interfaces (from `.ui` or binary files, for example).
The system design would be such that the core controller would somehow load it's presentation from remote source.

My question is: Are there any library that could provide this kind of flexibility in GUI applications development? How to implement such a architecture?

Thank you in advance for responses.

Comment: Can't you already edit/move toolbars, dock windows etc. in most GUI toolkits?

Comment: The problem I see with loading .ui files at runtime, is that ui files are ran through the 'uic' utility at compile time to generate the cpp code for them.

Comment: Hm, another thought. Qt's Designer app is capable of creating/editing ui files and displaying them without compilation (by using the Preview feature). Maybe you should look into the source of Designer/Creator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QUiLoader](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/quiloader.html) to load `.ui` files at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a GUI based on html which can be modified at run time.

The new version of Qt has a gui/themes based on an html like design language - Qt quick or something?

Comment: Also known as Qt Declarative: http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Graphics/Kinetic/DeclarativeUI